# How to validate against full model data in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### TL;DR

In my `Serializer.validate` method, I need to be able to access `attrs['field']` and fall back to `self.instance.field` if it's not set in the incoming data, and I'm wondering if there is a common pattern to do so.

### The Problem

Take the example from the [Object-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) section of the DRF Serializers documentation:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        Check that start is before finish.
        """
        if attrs['start'] > attrs['finish']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return attrs
```

(This uses a normal `Serializer`, but imagine it's a `ModelSerializer` for an `Event` model.)

When an event is created, or updated where both the `start` and `finish` attributes are included in the data, then this serializer works as expected.

However, if you make a request such as:

```py
client.patch(f"/events/{event.id}", {"start": "2021-01-01"})
```

Then the serializer will fail, because trying to access `attrs['finish']` results in a `KeyError`. In this case, I need to be able fall back to `self.instance.finish`, since the `start < finish` validation is still necessary.

Is there a common pattern that solves this problem?

### Current Solution

You can solve this by adding a snippet to the start of all `validate` methods:

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    full_attrs = attrs
    if self.instance is not None:
        full_attrs = {
            **self.to_internal_value(self.__class__(self.instance).data),
            **full_attrs,
        }
```

Then use `full_attrs` in place of `attrs`. This adds the serialized version of the instance data to `attrs`.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

(The one "downside" with this is that it could prevent otherwise valid updates if the data loses it's integrity. So for instance, if a developer updates the database directly so that `event.start` is later than `event.finish`, an API user will no longer be able to update `event.description` since this validation would fail. But I think the pros definitely outweigh the cons, at least for my current use case.)

Answer (score 8):

I'll offer my take on this question because I have come across this problem in one of my projects.

I did the validation check in the model layer because:

1. You no longer have to run the validation check on the serializer layer.
2. The validation logic is closer to the database layer so you don't have to worry about "bad" data being created if someone decides to use django's ORM and create objects from the backend (e.g. import scripts).
3. You validation logic sits closer to the code where the object is being created/saved so it's easier to debug

Validating it on the model layer is pretty simple. You can override the `save` method of the model class or the `clean` method and running the `clean` method (or `full_clean`) in the `save` method. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class MyModel(models.Model):
    start = ...
    finish = ...
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.finish < self.start:
            raise ValidationError("Finish must occur after start")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now here's the thing about django's ValidationError. DRF doesn't know how to handle it. If you passed some invalid data to the serializer, you won't get a nice 400 response. To get DRF to handle the error, you write your own custom error handler and set it as the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` in your `settings.py`.

```py
# myapp/exceptions.py

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.response import Response


def django_error_handler(exc, context):
    """Handle django core's errors."""
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is None and isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        return Response(status=400, data=exc.message_dict)
    return response
```

```py
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'myapp.exceptions.django_error_handler'
}
```

### Last Note

I notice you're using the generic `serializers.Serializer` class for your serializer. If you already have an `Event` model, it's easier to use [`serializers.ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) as this abstracts away the a lot of the object creation/update logic. Another benefit is that since it will look at your model's field definitions, it builds the fields according to how you have the fields specified in your model so you don't need to to define your fields in your serializer (e.g. If the field has a `max_length`, it'll create corresponding DRF field with a max length).

Comment: Hey, really appreciate the thorough response.

Regarding moving the validation to the model: this is actually exactly what I used to do (call `full_clean()` on `save()`), but switched because of the creator of DRF's remarks on this issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3144

As you can see, it's super contentious, but once I went "all in" on the serializer approach (i.e. use the serializer literally everywhere you update the model), it's worked pretty well. That said I do not think your approach is a bad one at all; the `django_error_handler` is great!

Comment: And thanks for the comment about the `ModelSerializer` -- I kept it as `Serializer` there since I wanted to match the example from the docs, but you're right that it would be much better to use a `ModelSerializer`. Probably should have just switched it in my question for clarity.

Comment: I would add emphasis that Django ORM does not necessarily call .save(), this is mostly related to bulk actions like bulk_create/bulk_update/update additionally in case of ModelForm which also calls  full_clean , it would be called twice for correct data

Comment: Valid points! I'd say @iklinac's answer is even better since the CheckConstraints are enforced on the database level.

Comment: But there I cannot use `objects` (Model Manager) in order to validate some data with already existing data

Answer (score 2):

Rather additionally enforce integrity on database level by using [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) so you have no worries about inducing dirty data

```
class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(
                    finish > models.F("start")     
                    )
                ),
                name="start_gt_finish",
            )
        ]
```

To answer upon the choice of validation there is really no optimal solution. If your app is mix of `ModelForms`/Django admin and API it might be tempting to go with calling `full_clean()` but that might be also problematic as you would need to patch it somewhere as `validate()` does not call `full_clean()` nor properly converts all Django `ValidationErrors`.

---

I would say your solution seems fine and serves as serializer validation layer, and in case without database constraint you might check if start and stop are non existent in `attrs` to avoid validation check if patched data does not contain either start or stop