# How to permit only users with a particular domain to login? Django google authentication

Tags: python, django, google-authentication, python-social-auth

I'm trying to limit the access to a page only to logged users.
I used the google authentication, but it let every account to log in; instead i want to avoid every domains different from 'fermi.mo.it'.
A google account like luca@gmail.com shouldn't be able to login, while an account like luca@fermi.mo.it should be able to.

I noticed this code to make it, but it doesnt work.
It says: "No module named 'social_core'" but i installed it.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['fermi.mo.it']
```

These are all the modules that i installed:
[image]

Comment: add authentiation filter ?

Comment: What do you mean? How can i add it?

Answer (score 0):

If django is not able to find the module, make sure that you have added the `'social_django'` ro installed apps.

Other soution is that you can create a validator at level Serializer or model according you. Which of them choose? That's other topic.

1. [Django Model field validation vs DRF Serializer field
   validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218802/django-model-field-validation-vs-drf-serializer-field-validation)
2. [How to validate against full model data in DjangoREST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912181/how-to-validate-against-full-model-data-in-django-rest-framework)

You only have to check if the email contains the string `'fermi.mo.it'`. If don't, raise and exception.

The documentation of each one: [Django Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/) and [Validators DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/).

Comment: Oh, i didn't add social_django. Anyway now it doesn't throw an exception even if the domain is different from fermi.mo.it, everyone can login :(
I haven't tried the second solution yet because the first one seems to be easier to implement

Answer (score 0):

I can see that OP has already installed the app

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

So, now OP needs to

1 Ensure one has added the application to `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_django',
    ...
)
```

2 After that, sync the database to create needed models

```
./manage.py migrate
```

3 Then, one wants to [limit the emails that Google shows in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110652/7109869)

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
        'hd': 'fermi.mo.it'
    }
```

4 Finally, one wants to limit the emails that can sign in

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['fermi.mo.it']
```